# SslStream Class equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, encryption, tcp

I have TCP/IP server Client Program. 
I want to Implement Encrypted Communication in TCP/IP.

I came to know [SSLStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) is one of the way to Implement Encrypted Communication in C#. Is there any easy option to implement Encryption in TCP/IP?

Note: I have heard about [IPSec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipsec) can be implemented at very low level.

Comment: I'd consider GnuTLS. I found OpenSSL rather annoying API wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One standard cross-platform solution is [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ssl.html):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The OpenSSL ssl library implements the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL v2/v3) and Transport Layer Security (TLS v1) protocols. It provides a rich API which is documented here.
>
> At first the library must be initialized; see SSL_library_init(3).
>
> Then an SSL_CTX object is created as a framework to establish TLS/SSL enabled connections (see SSL_CTX_new(3)). Various options regarding certificates, algorithms etc. can be set in this object.
>
> When a network connection has been created, it can be assigned to an SSL object. After the SSL object has been created using SSL_new(3), SSL_set_fd(3) or SSL_set_bio(3) can be used to associate the network connection with the object.
>
> Then the TLS/SSL handshake is performed using SSL_accept(3) or SSL_connect(3) respectively. SSL_read(3) and SSL_write(3) are used to read and write data on the TLS/SSL connection. SSL_shutdown(3) can be used to shut down the TLS/SSL connection.

Comment: How Do I use this with TCP/IP program?

Comment: @DineshkumarPonnusamy Download the source code and look at the examples provided. Google for example of usage. [Here is one](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/83final/ba554_90007/ch04s03.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try crypto++

[Crypto++ Library is a free C++ class library of cryptographic schemes](http://www.cryptopp.com/)

Comment: Crypto++ Library provides Encryption of a data or an object. I want encrypted communication in TCP/IP connection.